# Keystore Does Not Exist Error Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, keystore, android-keystore

I am getting an error on android studio, it is as follows:

```
android:failed with 1 error
build.gradle
keystore file does not exist:
C:\Users\Brandy\Documents\BoxFan\platforms\android\..\..\..\key.jks
```

I have a keystore file created and linked but it's in the root folder so maybe this is why the error is happening, I am not sure what folder the above code is alluding to since the dots prevent me from seeing the full path.

Does anyone know what folder my keystore should be in as stated above or how to fix this error another way?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see where its pointing by going to File > Project Structure > Modules > Signing Configs

[image]

Or you can open Terminal and enter: ./gradlew signingReport